# Potential causes for unusually long queries (postgres)

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, postgresql-performance, performance-tuning, troubleshooting

Recently we've noticed some `SELECT` queries taking an unusually long time to complete and are a bit stumped on what the reason could be.

Looking at DB (and server) CPU and IO during the time the queries are ran we don't see any spikes; so it doesn't look like it has to do with a heavy DB load.

Further, while we don't believe the rows are locked during these queries, if they were they'd be locked for updates, which shouldn't be affecting these `SELECT` queries.

Unusually long in this case means we're seeing what should be very light, simple queries taking around 45s.

Is there anything else besides a heavy DB load and lock (both of which seem to not apply to our case here) that could cause a query to lag like this?

**Update** with a bit more context that may be helpful:

These aren't just some one-off queries. They are run thousands of times a day, for literally the exact same record, and normally complete perfectly fine.

Then, seemingly out of nowhere, with no extra load on the DB or anything else obvious that may affect its performance, the query lags.

We have appropriate indexes in place on the columns that are in the `WHERE` clause and running `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` returns nothing odd.

And when we say "simple" we mean something as straightforward as this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM abcd WHERE example = 'ex' LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Yes, there are many reasons for a query to be slow. Enumerating them all is pointless.

Comment: Very difficult to say without any concrete information about data architecture and the query itself. Could be a missing index for example

Comment: Enumerating the possibilities would give the OP a useful checklist they could go through to enable them diagnose such queries and would answer this question in a way that it could be used by others also. I'm not following why that would be pointless?

Comment: Thanks for the responses so far everyone! And good thinking @Sotis about the index. We do however have indexes already in place.

I've updated the original question with a bit more context that hopefully gives a better picture of the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the new information, but still difficult to say, I'm sorry! Maybe if you have many updates the table and indexes could be bloated. Is there an autovacuum running smoothly?

Comment: No worries, it's understandable since it sounds like the issues could be many and dependent on the data arch.

The table generally doesn't get a lot of updates and we'd expect if bloat were the issue we'd see the queries lag more often, as there are a lot of reads (much more than updates). But we'll double check autovacuum just to be sure. 

Thanks again for the help @Sotis!